# textField.text is always empty In dynamic customized tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have 2 different custom TableViewCells.
One contains a label, and textfield.
another contains a label, and textview.

the TableView of the two cells has "save" button to insert those text values as its new cell.

the problem is that I cannot get the value of theTextField.text what i've typed, but textView.text.

I can assign a new value programmatically as like

```
customCellForTextFiled.textField.text = @"Why so serious?";
```

but I cannot get the value of textField.text.
it shows me always empty like @""

I spent over a day on this problem.
It used to work, but after a small refactoring it has a bug like this.
CAn you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `UITextField` is actually connected as `IBOutlet` or initialized programmatically. Try to

```
NSLog(@"customCellForTextFiled.textField = %@", customCellForTextFiled.textField);
```

and check the result is not `(null)`

Comment: NSLog(@"customCellForTextFiled.textField = %@", customCellForTextFiled.textField) is not (Null), is just @"".
if I put static value on the textfield in Storyboard, NSLog says the value. However, I put other values, it doesn't recognize its new values.